# Rundeck ignoring node

Tags: rundeck

I'm trying execute a job on know node by rundeck server, but when execute it was ignored and job run on server local (Rundeck Server).
Anyone went through this situation?

- Rundeck 3.1.3-20191204
- Node configured in Project Setting
- It's possible see the host in Node menu of Project
- Rundeck server can access via ssh the node.

Comment: Guys I managed to solve, after make all setup to Rundeck know and access de node you need go to Project Setting > Edit Configuration > Default Node Executor and change to SSH.
The problem occured because my project was created like LOCAL default node executor.

Comment: Hi Weyder, that's great! Feel free to submit this as an answer and accept it as the best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to solve, after make all setup to Rundeck know and access de node you need go to Project Setting > Edit Configuration > Default Node Executor and change to SSH. The problem occured because my project was created like LOCAL default node executor.